# How do I remove single children in a tree?

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures, recursive-datastructures

Given the following tree:

```json
{
  "name": "svg",
  "type": "element",
  "value": "",
  "attributes": {
    "xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
    "width": "1440",
    "height": "1080"
  },
  "children": [{
    "name": "g",
    "type": "element",
    "value": "",
    "attributes": {},
    "children": [{
      "name": "g",
      "type": "element",
      "value": "",
      "attributes": {},
      "children": [{
        "name": "g",
        "type": "element",
        "value": "",
        "attributes": {
          "fill": "#627580"
        },
        "children": [{
          "name": "g",
          "type": "element",
          "value": "",
          "attributes": {
            "stroke-linejoin": "round"
          },
          "children": [{
            "name": "path",
            "type": "element",
            "value": "",
            "attributes": {
              "d": "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"
            },
            "children": []
          }, {
            "name": "path",
            "type": "element",
            "value": "",
            "attributes": {
              "d": "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"
            },
            "children": []
          }, {
            "name": "path",
            "type": "element",
            "value": "",
            "attributes": {
              "d": "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"
            },
            "children": []
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "g",
          "type": "element",
          "value": "",
          "attributes": {
            "stroke-linejoin": "round"
          },
          "children": [{
            "name": "path",
            "type": "element",
            "value": "",
            "attributes": {
              "d": "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"
            },
            "children": []
          }, {
            "name": "path",
            "type": "element",
            "value": "",
            "attributes": {
              "d": "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"
            },
            "children": []
          }, {
            "name": "path",
            "type": "element",
            "value": "",
            "attributes": {
              "d": "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"
            },
            "children": []
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

...which is a representation of this HTML:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1440" height="1080">
  <g>
    <g>
      <g fill="#627580">
        <g stroke-linejoin="round">
          <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
          <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
          <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
        </g>
        <g stroke-linejoin="round">
          <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
          <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
          <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

How do I transform this data structure recursively in JavaScript so all groups `<g>` that have only one child `<g>` are collapsed and their children are assigned to its parent?

Expected result would be this:

```json
{
  "name": "svg",
  "type": "element",
  "value": "",
  "attributes": {
    "xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
    "width": "1440",
    "height": "1080"
  },
  "children": [{
    "name": "g",
    "type": "element",
    "value": "",
    "attributes": {},
    "children": [{
      "name": "g",
      "type": "element",
      "value": "",
      "attributes": {
        "stroke-linejoin": "round"
      },
      "children": [{
        "name": "path",
        "type": "element",
        "value": "",
        "attributes": {
          "d": "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"
        },
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "path",
        "type": "element",
        "value": "",
        "attributes": {
          "d": "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"
        },
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "path",
        "type": "element",
        "value": "",
        "attributes": {
          "d": "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"
        },
        "children": []
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "g",
      "type": "element",
      "value": "",
      "attributes": {
        "stroke-linejoin": "round"
      },
      "children": [{
        "name": "path",
        "type": "element",
        "value": "",
        "attributes": {
          "d": "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"
        },
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "path",
        "type": "element",
        "value": "",
        "attributes": {
          "d": "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"
        },
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "path",
        "type": "element",
        "value": "",
        "attributes": {
          "d": "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"
        },
        "children": []
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

...which is a representation of this HTML:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1440" height="1080">
  <g>
      <g fill="#627580">
        <g stroke-linejoin="round">
          <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
          <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
          <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
        </g>
        <g stroke-linejoin="round">
          <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
          <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
          <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
        </g>
      </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Ideally there should not be a `<g>` element remaining with a single child `<g>`. In other words:

```html
<g>
  <g>
  ...
  </g>
</g>
```

will be transformed into

```html
<g>
...
</g>
```

This is my attempt:

```js
const collapseGroups = node => {
  if (node.children && node.children.length > 0) {
    node.children.forEach(child => {
      collapseGroups(child)
    })
    if (node.name == 'g' && 
      node.children.length == 1 && 
      node.children[0].name == 'g') {
        node.children = node.children[0].children;
    }
  }
}
```

NB: My input is a SVG file, which is already automatically parsed into the above mentioned JS object.

Comment: I'm going to get reamed for this, but the answer to the question in your title is "call the fire department".

Comment: What is the data structure? A string?

Comment: @trincot Added extra info in the question

Comment: I don't think that clarifies it. What is the *input* data type? Is that HTML already parsed into a JS nested object? Is it the object that needs to be mutated?

Comment: @trincot a JS object that has the above structure.

Comment: So what is the problem then? Can't you just check that `children.length == 1` and act accordingly? Have you tried to do something like that? Can you share your attempt?

Comment: Also, can you give the completed JavaScript object for your example?

Comment: I think he (@Miki) want something like this: `[ [data] ]` -> `[data]`

Comment: @trincot Added extra info to question

Comment: But the JavaScript object? Can you provide it?

Comment: @trincot You got it

Comment: Are you sure you want to lose the attributes when you delete a level of `g`??

Comment: @trincot That is not my issue. I already take care of that. My function above is a simplified version for clarity. In my original function I do something like       node.attributes = {...node.attributes, ...node.children[0].attributes}

Comment: OK, it's clear. Posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive function on each node. If it detects it is of type "g", and only has one child, then the node absorbs the child, merging also the attributes property:

```js
function simplify(node) {
    return  node.name === 'g' && node.children.length === 1 
                              && node.children[0].name === 'g'
          ? { 
                ...simplify(node.children[0]), 
                attributes: { // Merge attributes of the two nodes that merge into one
                    ...node.attributes,
                    ...node.children[0].attributes
                }
            }
          : {
                ...node, 
                children: node.children.map(simplify)
            };
}

// Sample input:
let root = {
  "name": "svg",
  "type": "element",
  "value": "",
  "attributes": {
    "xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
    "width": "1440",
    "height": "1080"
  },
  "children": [{
    "name": "g",
    "type": "element",
    "value": "",
    "attributes": {},
    "children": [{
      "name": "g",
      "type": "element",
      "value": "",
      "attributes": {},
      "children": [{
        "name": "g",
        "type": "element",
        "value": "",
        "attributes": {
          "fill": "#627580"
        },
        "children": [{
          "name": "g",
          "type": "element",
          "value": "",
          "attributes": {
            "stroke-linejoin": "round"
          },
          "children": [{
            "name": "path",
            "type": "element",
            "value": "",
            "attributes": {
              "d": "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"
            },
            "children": []
          }, {
            "name": "path",
            "type": "element",
            "value": "",
            "attributes": {
              "d": "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"
            },
            "children": []
          }, {
            "name": "path",
            "type": "element",
            "value": "",
            "attributes": {
              "d": "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"
            },
            "children": []
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "g",
          "type": "element",
          "value": "",
          "attributes": {
            "stroke-linejoin": "round"
          },
          "children": [{
            "name": "path",
            "type": "element",
            "value": "",
            "attributes": {
              "d": "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"
            },
            "children": []
          }, {
            "name": "path",
            "type": "element",
            "value": "",
            "attributes": {
              "d": "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"
            },
            "children": []
          }, {
            "name": "path",
            "type": "element",
            "value": "",
            "attributes": {
              "d": "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"
            },
            "children": []
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
};

root = simplify(root);

console.log(root);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a basic traversal of the structure, however, if you encounter a `g` tag that has a single `g` tag child, simply call `merge` on that child:

```js
var d = {'name': 'svg', 'type': 'element', 'value': '', 'attributes': {'xmlns': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'width': '1440', 'height': '1080'}, 'children': [{'name': 'g', 'type': 'element', 'value': '', 'attributes': {}, 'children': [{'name': 'g', 'type': 'element', 'value': '', 'attributes': {}, 'children': [{'name': 'g', 'type': 'element', 'value': '', 'attributes': {'fill': '#627580'}, 'children': [{'name': 'g', 'type': 'element', 'value': '', 'attributes': {'stroke-linejoin': 'round'}, 'children': [{'name': 'path', 'type': 'element', 'value': '', 'attributes': {'d': 'M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z'}, 'children': []}, {'name': 'path', 'type': 'element', 'value': '', 'attributes': {'d': 'M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z'}, 'children': []}, {'name': 'path', 'type': 'element', 'value': '', 'attributes': {'d': 'M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z'}, 'children': []}]}, {'name': 'g', 'type': 'element', 'value': '', 'attributes': {'stroke-linejoin': 'round'}, 'children': [{'name': 'path', 'type': 'element', 'value': '', 'attributes': {'d': 'M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z'}, 'children': []}, {'name': 'path', 'type': 'element', 'value': '', 'attributes': {'d': 'M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z'}, 'children': []}, {'name': 'path', 'type': 'element', 'value': '', 'attributes': {'d': 'M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z'}, 'children': []}]}]}]}]}]}
function merge(d){
    if (d.name != 'g' || d.children.length > 1 || d.children[0].name != 'g'){
       return {...d, 'children':d.children.map(merge)}
    }
    return merge(d.children[0])
}
console.log(merge(d))
```